# Property 'Int32 Year' is not defined for type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' When comparing year in two dates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've got strange exception when comparing year in datetime.

sample code:

```
_dbContext.Details.Where(x => x.Person.Birth.Year == date.Year);
```

Where both Birth and date are not nullable DateTime.

Exception message:

`` Message: System.ArgumentException : Property 'Int32 Year' is not defined for type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' ``

I tried to run the code from unit tests with database set up in memory.

Comment: What are the types of `Birth` and `date`?

Comment: Person.Birth.Value.Year

Comment: it's not nullable. Posted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My model definition was wrong and I didn't specify foreign key correctly.

It looked similar to that (after renaming from `PerId` to `PersonId` the problem was gone):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime Birth {get; set;}
}

public class Details 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int PerId {get; set;}
    public Person Person {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's nullable, you need to access:

```
date.Value.Year
```

Comment: Yields to NRE when `date` is null, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems you have "DateTime?" instead of "DateTime". That way, you have to check something like that:

```
_dbContext.Details.Where(x => date.HasValue && (x.Person.Birth.Year == date.Value.Year));
```